# Limit size of a collection.

Tags: predicate-logic

I am trying to express the constraints of a database domain. A database domain can be limits the values that can be stored in a single cell of a table.

The restriction I am trying to describe is the following: All elements of the collection must be part of the natural numbers, 0, a . or one of the letters A or B. Besides that a maximum length needs to be added to the collection.

So far I got:

> $∀x; x \in \mathbb N  \lor  x \in \{ \cdot, 0, D, B \}$

Am I doing it correct if I write it as follows (VERSION_NUMBER is the name of the domain)?

> $(∀x; x \in \mathbb N  \lor  x \in \{ \cdot, 0, D, B \}) \land \text {VERSION_NUMBER} \le |17|$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I just tried editing it but I am not able to escape the bracket in the way explained in your link \{.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA how would I combine the two?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA does this not express that every element of VERSION_NUMBER is allowed to have a length of 17? What I tried to say was that the first restrictions apply to every element and the length constraint applies to the collection.